# d3.js PopUp window with mouseout and mouseover

Tags: javascript, d3.js, popup

I have created a Popup functionality in a GeoMap by using d3.js. The following part of codes shows the specific node as a circle when I move mouse over the circle, it will be shown a Popup window.

```
g2.selectAll(".details")
.data(d3.entries(json1))
.enter()
.append("circle")
.attr("r",0.5)
.attr("transform",function(d) { return "translate("+ projection([
    d.value.lon,
    d.value.lat
]) + ')'; })
.attr("fill","white")
.attr("stroke","steelblue")
.on("mouseover", function(d) {
    div.transition()
       .duration(500)
       .style("opacity", .9);
    div .html(
        '<a href= "' + d.value.url + '">' + //with a link
          d.value.name +"</a>" + "<br/>" + d.value.status)
        .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
        .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 30) + "px");
})
```

As you can see, the **mouseover** function is working. But when I zoom in or drag the map, it will exist some bugs like this:

[image: failure]

You can see the Popup window always locates in the same position(I believe the reason is that the location is specific, not dynamically change when I drag the map).

Now, I am wondering, how can I create a **mouseout** functionality, in order to remove the Popup window when I put the mouse outside the circle(node)?

Or is there some way to fix the bugs in the **mouseover** functionality?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

To handle the `mouseout` you can just add this to your chain:

```
.on("mouseout", function() {
    div.transition()
       .duration(500)
       .style("opacity", 0)
       .on('end', function() {
           div.html('');
       });
});
```

As for keeping the popup displayed in the correct position when you're zooming or dragging it's difficult to know the best way to handle this without seeing your code, but could you place the popup div inside the selection that is zoomed/dragged so that it automatically updates? Alternatively you'd need to reposition your popup on drag/zoom - you'd probably have to save the marker position in your `mouseover` function and then use that to recalculate the coordinates in the zoom and drag functions as necessary.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I have tried to add the mouseout event to the code, it could work somehow. But when I move the mouse on the node, sometimes it does not show the pop up window. When I delete the mouseout code. it will be showed. I am not sure, where is the problem.